# bootbox and jquery validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

i am using bootbox dialog with a form (has only one textbox and one textarea) and i am trying to validate it with jquery validation plugin.

Here is my code

```
var templateDialog="<form action=\"#\" id=\"create-form\" name=\"create-form\" class=\"form\" method=\"post\">"+
"<div class=\"controls\">"+
"<input type=\"text\" id=\"field1\" name=\"field1\"  />"+   
"</div>"+

"<div class=\"controls\">"+
"<textarea id=\"field2\" name=\"field2\"  rows=\"13\"></textarea>"+ 
"</div>"+
"</form>";


bootbox.dialog(templateDialog,
[{
   "label" : "Cancel",
   "class" : "btn",
   "callback": function() {

    }
  }, {
        "label" : "Save",
        "class" : "btn-primary",
        "callback": function() {

        $('#create-form').validate({
           errorElement: 'span', 
           errorClass: 'errorblock', 
           focusInvalid: false, 
           errorContainer: ".alerterror",
           ignore: "",
           rules: {
                    field1: {
                    required: true
                  },
                    field2: {
                    required: true
                  }
           },

           errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
               $(element).closest('.controls').append(error);
               console.log(element);
           },

           submitHandler: function (form) {
                        //manual submit
           }
        });


                return false;
            }
        }]
        ,
        {
            header: 'Create',
            css: 'large-modal'
        }
        );
```

with the code above i dont get any error and also i dont get the success alert, what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use livequery plugin to add validation in that form [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

as ;

```
 $('#create-form').livequery(function(){
    $(this).validate({
       .....
       .....
    });
 });
```

Comment: sorry but i am not that i understand what you mean.

Comment: i get an error that object has no method livequery, but i dont think that this is the issue, i have access to form and form elements event withou the live event.

Comment: firstly add the script in the code and then use this function, also my concern is that the I think validate plugin is unable to add the event of submit on that form since you added the validate function on the dom that is added after the DOM is already loaded

Comment: you are correct the solution is to add .form() in validate $("#form").validate({...}).form();